# What exact size tires ORIGINALLY came on an older Giant mens Cypress bicycle?

Tags: tire

I have an 12-15 year old mens Giant Cypress bicycle. I am trying to find out what exact tire size originally came with the bike. I have been riding on smaller replacement tires that now need to be replaced. The smaller size that I have been riding on is 700 x 35C - 28 x 1 5/8 x 1 3/8. These tires are smaller (thinner) than the original. I would like to know the original size and if there are any options besides these current tires which I never cared for anyway. Thanks, Frank

Comment: Who cares? Or, to put it another way, why do you think you'll necessarily find the exact size the bike originally came with to be the best for you?

Answer (score 2):

The 2005 Giant Cypress came with 700x38c tyres.
https://www.bicyclebluebook.com/value-guide/product/92884/

Large volume tyres are growing in popularity over the last couple of years, so you should be able to find many good options in this size.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the model year 2002 came with 40mm tires, which will be a bit wider than 35s. Check out the Sawtooth tire by Specialized.